# .NET String.Split Appears to Malfunction for Non-Latin Characters

Tags: .net, string

Trying to split paragraphs into sentences: my text is mixed Latin and Armenian alphabet characters; when I invoke String.Split, the split is at the wrong position. I am attempting to split on periods/question marks/exclamation points. Could this be a bug in .NET? Or did I miss something?

[Link to DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sMBFuf). If you run that code, you will see that the first sentence is *"The Temple of Garni (Armenian: Գառնիի տաճար"*, which is wrong, it is only *part* of the first sentence.

```
    string combinedParas = @"The Temple of Garni (Armenian: Գառնիի տաճար, Gaṙnii tačar, [ˈgɑrnii ˈtɑtʃɑʁ])[a] is the only standing Greco-Roman colonnaded building in Armenia and the former Soviet Union. Built in the Ionic order in the village of Garni, Armenia, it is the best-known structure and symbol of pre-Christian Armenia.";

    var sentences = combinedParas.Split(new[] { ',', '?', '!' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach(var s in sentences) {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Mostly asking out of curiosity; I have already moved-on and written my own split function to handle the issue at hand.

Comment: You're splitting the string by any occurrences of `,` and `?` and `!`. The string splitting doesn't know anything about natural language parsing, so it gives you the first substring of characters up to the first `,`. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Duh! Thanks for spotting what should have been obvious. I meant to split on period, not comma.

Comment: @ActualRandy split on period?